# How can I use laravel all functions in root file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I use Laravel facade in Laravel root directory?

I have created one file: **mail.php** in Laravel root directory (inside)

So how can I use mail facade in that PHP file?

Comment: I dont fully understand your intentions here...

Comment: Maybe there are a way to do what you want in a proper way instead. If you tell us more we could probably guide you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$path = public_path();
require_once  $path.'/mail.php';
```

Comment: Hi @win, let me know for mail in laravel we need to configure smtp or not?

Comment: @ Rajan, Yes, you should configure SMTP
you can see the SMTP configuration template in config/mail.php